# Upgrading ImageMagick RHEL 5

Tags: php, rpm, rhel5, package-management, imagemagick

We have been using `ImageMagick` for quite some time with out any trouble.

However, today we can across an pdf we were trying to convert into a jpg thumbnail, which would fail:

`$ convert example.pdf -resize 600 thumb.jpg`

```
Error: /rangecheck in --run--
Operand stack:
   --dict:12/21(L)--   Sh5   0.0   --nostringval--   true   14460   0   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1846   1   3   %oparray_pop   1845   1   3   %oparray_pop   1829   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   1   1   --nostringval--   %for_pos_int_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1158/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:75/200(L)--   --dict:106/127(ro)(G)--   --dict:285/300(ro)(G)--   --dict:22/25(L)--   --dict:4/6(L)--   --dict:25/40(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:9/15(L)--   --dict:5/5(L)--   --dict:2/5(L)--   --dict:1/1(ro)(G)--   --dict:9/15(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
convert: Postscript delegate failed `example.pdf'.
convert: missing an image filename `thumb.jpg'.
```

So on a test environment (Ubuntu) I was able to install the latest version of `ImageMagick` and was able to convert this pdf -> jpg just fine.

The trouble is upgrading this package on RHEL. There is not an update available for `ImageMagick` using yum. So I did this:

```
wget http://www.imagemagick.org/download/linux/CentOS/x86_64/ImageMagick-6.8.4-4.x86_64.rpm
yum erase ImageMagick
yum install --nogpgcheck ImageMagick-6.7.9-6.x86_64.rpm
```

Note: That `yum erase` removed the `ImageMagick-devel` as well as the `ImageMagick` package.

But now I get this message when trying to run any command line php script:
`Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/imagick.so' - libWand.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

And I am nervous to restart apache because our production web-app relies on php-imagick to resize images.

How can I get php to find the new `ImageMagick`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You will need to recompile php against the newer ImageMagick, or (the quicker and safer solution) downgrade imagemagick again.

That buys you some time to update to RHEL 6, which has a newer imagemagick.

Comment: How unfortunate...